# Connect to mongohq in a Cocoa application

Tags: cocoa, mongohq

I am trying to connect to a mongohq database from a Cocoa application, but I really don't know there to start. I googled for it but it does not seem to be something useful online.

Do you know if there is a simple way to do it?

Obviously no one will write the code for me. I would like just to be pointed to the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you just having trouble finding an objective-c driver for MongoDB or do you have that and need help specifically connecting to a database hosted on MongoHQ?

Comment: I can't find any objective-c driver. I see here (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Drivers) that there aren't drivers for objective-c; I think that there is a way to use another driver (but I don't know how to do that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look a bit further down the page you mentioned in your comment (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Drivers), you'll see there is a community-supported Objective-C driver. http://github.com/timburks/NuMongoDB. It's for the Nu programming language but they modularized all their libraries so you should just be able to use it alone. In theory.